# animation function is not applied to each elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

here is a problem i am facing in my progressbar. i have data-percent attribute in my "pro-bar" class . each data-percent is different but when in browser i'am getting first pro-bar's data-percent value applied to all

Here is my code:

```
$('.pro-bar').each(function( i, elem ){
    var percent = $('.pro-bar').attr('data-percent'),
        barparcent = Math.round(percent*5.56),
        $elem = $(this);

        console.log(percent);

    $elem.animate({'width':barparcent}, 2000, 'easeInOutExpo');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is how you are referring to your pro-bar inside the each. Use "this" to refer to the current element, not a general class selector.

```
$('.pro-bar').each(function( i, elem ){
    var percent = $(this).attr('data-percent'),//change here
        barparcent = Math.round(percent*5.56),
        $elem = $(this);

        console.log(percent);

    $elem.animate({'width':barparcent}, 2000, 'easeInOutExpo');
});
```

Further explanation:

`$(".pro-bar").attr("data-percent")` gets all of the `.pro-bar`, then `.attr("data-percent")` gets the value of the first element (as does most other similar jquery methods). Then as you loop through each element, this same effect is called multiple times.